# How can I change the internal clock of Argo Workflows?

Tags: argo-workflows, argo

Whenever I am running a cron-job in Argo Workflows I use pd.Timestamp.now(). This offsets my local time with two hours however.

As I have a lot of jobs scheduled, I am not keen on changing the timezone for all of them. Instead, I am searching for some kind of global solution.